# How to disable current dates in bootstrap date picker

Tags: jquery

How to disable current dates in bootstrap date picker?

This is what I have so far:

```
$('#projEndDt').datepicker({
    onSelect: function(selected) {
        enableDisableNextBtn();
    }
});
```

Comment: You mean to say today's date?

Comment: ` useCurrent: false,`:- http://jsfiddle.net/Ashokkumargupta/m2fjw57b/47/

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {$('#projEndDt').datetimepicker({useCurrent: false});});
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.